# Create clickable URL in PHP

Tags: php

Trying to create a clickable URL in PHP. If you visit www.wheels4rent.net/test00.html and input location and date clicking the 'quote' will take you to the list_car5.php page. At right of this page is a 'book now' button that does not work and the text hyperlink below this. problem is when clicking the text hyperlink instead of giving me the www.thrifty.co.uk URL it gives me www.wheels4rent.net/www.thrifty.co.uk URL which obviously does not display webpage. Please assist. Also i need to also create the text hyperlink within my 'book now' button instead. below is code

```
$url = (string)$car->book;

echo "<tr><td width=200px><' align='right' style='padding:1px; width:100px'><b>".$car->cartype."</b><br>".$car->carsipp."<br>".$car->transmission."</td><td><b>".$car->carexample."</b></td><td><b>&pound;".$car->price."
</b><br>Unlimited Miles</b><br><a href='$url'><input type='submit' name='Book Now' value='Book Now'><br>book now<br></a></td></tr>"; 
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of one of your URLs? Also, I'd change the single quotes into double quotes, specially for your href attribute, I'm not sure HTML supports single quotes for that.

Comment: OP. Please keep this within SO. Using my websites contact page to request further help isn't a great idea, nor helpful for other people who may have the same problem as you.

Comment: added http:// in <a> tag see folowing code <a href='http://$url'><input type='submit' name='Book Now' value='Book Now'><br>book now<br></a></td></tr>"; But the problem i have is it gives me reply http://%20www..etc

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code (the entire line) with formatting so we can see what you've done easier.

Comment: it will not allow me to add more url's until i have reached score 10 in my reputation? but you can see from above code i place http:// and got %20 before the www.

Comment: foreach($xmlDoc->car as $car)
{
$url = (string)$car->book;

echo "<tr><td width=200px><img src='".$car->carimage."' align='right' style='padding:1px; width:100px'><b>".$car->cartype."</b><br>".$car->carsipp."<br>".$car->transmission."</td><td><b>".$car->carexample."</b></td><td><b>&pound;".$car->price."
</b><br>Unlimited Miles</b><br><a href='http://$url'><input type='submit' name='Book Now' value='Book Now'><br>book now<br></a></td></tr>";



 
}
echo "</table>";

Comment: Check the value of $url. It sounds like you've got a space at the beginning that's being URL encoded.

Comment: checked value of $url and no space

Comment: as you can see from above code no space before, after or within $url

Comment: I can only comment on what you've given. Somewhere in your code, a space has been added and encoded.

Comment: if i replace $url with any link, ie: www.yahoo.co.uk it works fine, but with $url i get the error and cannot see any spaces in code?/

Comment: ok found and rectified problem. Code that works but with hyperlink instead of button is  <a href='http://".trim($car->book)."'><br>book now<br></a></td></tr>";   How can i create a button that will work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add http:// to the beginning of the URL in the `<a>` tag. I can't even read the code you've posted, so that's the only answer I can give.

Comment: added http:// in <a> tag see folowing code  <a href='http://$url'><input type='submit' name='Book Now' value='Book Now'><br>book now<br></a></td></tr>";
But the problem i have is it gives me reply http://%20www..etc

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping your  in an , use the onclick attribute of the  tag.

```
<input type='submit' name='Book Now' value='Book Now' 
   onclick="javascript:window.location('http://www.thrifty.co.uk')" />
<a href="http://www.thrifty.co.uk">Book Now</a>
```

Comment: I would use a <button> rather than a submit (we won't be submitting any forms).  I would also remove the "javascript:" indicator from something that can only accept javascript (the onclick).  `<button onclick='location.href="http://www.thrifty.co.uk";'>Book Now</button>`

Answer (score 0):

single quotes doesn't read variables.
So you could either write the whole html part in echo or you can simply close the php tag and enter the html code and then continue with your php code

for ex:

```
    <?php
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' onclick='<script>window.location('http://www.google.com')</script>'";
?>
```

or simply:

```
    <?php
-----//php code here
----
----
?>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="<script>window.location('http://www.google.com')</script>"/>
<?php
------
------
------
?>
```